# Install unsupported iOS version

Tags: ios, upgrade, ipod-touch, swift

I am developing iOS apps with Swift, and don't want to buy an Apple device to test them, and have just got an iPod 4gen which supports iOS up to 6.1.

I just wanna know if there is absolutely no possible way for me to install iOS 8 or 9? or even 7? I am willing to take all risks, I don't care if it get's super slow or even bricks my device while trying.

PS. I understand why the simulator doesn't have app store and why I can't run pre compiled apps on the simulator. As the simulator is x86 and the devices are on ARM processors. But an old device is stil the same processor so it should be possible to try out and unsupported OS, if I then run into apps crashing and other stuff not working is something else and I don't care about how badly it will run. I just wanna test my code out on an actual device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, iOS 6.1.6 is the latest version your iPod touch will support. There is absolutely no way to install iOS 7, 8, 9, or (extremely) likely anything later. It just won't work.

Answer (score -1):

No, you can't install older iOS version, because Apple do not seed this version anymore.

Comment: That's not really what the OP was asking.

Comment: When did Apple ever seed iOS 9 on iPod 4? Anymore seems to imply that they have done this in the past at some point.